# How to accept a ssl certificate in a bash or other script?

Tags: linux, ssl, svn, https, visualsvn-server

Normally I use visual svn to setup and configure my svn repositories.  By default visual svn uses https on port 8443.  I want to create a script that export or checkouts some part of my repositories in a newly created server (cloud server).  The only problem I am facing, is that when I try to do the svn export or checkout with the authentication arguments, I need to accept the ssl certificate on https.  Is there any bash option to tell the os to accept the certificate?

Thanks a lot, and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own CA, which has signed the server cert; you can trust that ca.

- put CA cert under `/etc/ssl/certs`
- run `c_rehash`
- add "ssl-trust-default-ca" within subversion configuration files. [See subversion configuration settings](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form of:

```
yes t | svn co --no-auth-cache --username USER --password PASSWORD https://repo directory
```

to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bash option which tells the OS to accept the certificate.

Comment: Thanks Murphy. Do you have any opinion in how to overcome this difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trust the unsigned certificate, or purchase a certificate from a trusted vendor.

Instructions [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn.sslcerts).